# Trying to use an asm function in an other, while compiling a lib.so using nasm

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

as said, I'm trying to re-us an asm function in an other, while compiling them both in libasm.so.
Basically, here is what I'm doing:

```
    strpbrk:

    init:  
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov r9, rdi
    mov r10, rsi
    mov rdx, -1
    loop:
    mov rbx, r9
    inc rdx
    add rbx, rdx
    movzx ebx, BYTE[rbx]

    mov [buf], ebx
    movzx rsi, WORD[buf]
    mov rdi, r10
    call strstr
    cmp rax, 0
    jne end

    cmp bl, 0
    jne loop

    end:
    leave
    ret

    SECTION .data

    buf db 0, 0
```

And here is the error:

```
    nasm -f elf64 src/strstr.asm -o src/strstr.o
    nasm -f elf64 src/strpbrk.asm -o src/strpbrk.o
    src/strpbrk.asm:23: error: symbol `strstr' undefined
    make: *** [Makefile:28: src/strpbrk.o] Error 1
```

Considering the fact that the strstr function I'm trying to call is made, and on the same makefile.

An idea how could I compile use them bot ?

Answer (score 0):

With nasm, you need to declare symbols from other translation units as `extern` or the assembler complains.  Read the [documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5) for details.

For your problem, write

```
extern strstr
```

in `strpbrk.asm` to tell nasm that `strstr` is an externally supplied symbol.